ROW_ID is Postgresql Database
Can we see the rowid of a specific row in Postgresql, as in Oracle?
In Oracle, there is a test case, when two rows of a table are identical and the task is to delete the second identical row (not the first one), we use row_id in a select query to point out the specific row that we are going to delete. Similarly, if this task has to be performed in Postgres, how will we identify and delete the second identical row?

You can number them with a row_number()over(partition by id) window function call then delete those where it's higher than 1, but it's easier to perform deduplication based on ctid.

This question should be answered already by How to use the physical location of rows (ROWID) in a DELETE statement. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See documentation for ctid.
